# Is there a function in Google app script to get an array of all sent mails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, gmail-api

I am developing a add-on program in google app script which gets all the gmail sent mails with there subject, body, attachment(if any). I have did this for the Inbox mail using getInboxThreads() function. Is there a function which does same for sent mails?

The program that i am writing is for any gmail user or a group of users how wants to save their gmail emails on the google drive for monitoring or any other operations.

Comment: To summarize from the linked answer, you can use the `list` method ([Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list)), adding `SENT` as the `labelIds` parameter. To use thgis from an Apps Script you will need to [enable Google Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

Comment: @DaImTo yes, which is why I added the comment, the approach is the same however. Would that not make it a duplicate?

Comment: Fair enough, removed the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the user.messages.list method to get a list of all the message ids for the user. You will then have to use user.messages.get To get the data about the message.

You can use the `'q': 'in:sent'` [parameter](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering) to get only the messages in the sent folder.

```
function myFunction() {
  var myMessages=Gmail.Users.Messages.list("me",{'maxResults': 5 , 'q': 'in:sent' }).messages;
  Logger.log(myMessages);
  for(var i=0;i<myMessages.length;i++){
    var id=myMessages[i].id;
    Gmail.Users.Messages.get('me', id).payload.headers.forEach(function(e){
      if(e.name=="Subject"||e.name=="From"){
        Logger.log(e.name+": "+e.value)
      }
     }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using your code but every time i run it, it gives me a error ""Gmail" is not defined." Might i be doing something wrong.

Comment: gmail is the service that you need to setup

Comment: I am sorry if i am asking to much from you. I am very new to this. So according to whatever knowledge i have and what i got from internet "Gmail.Users.Messages.list" is from google Gmail restful api services. So do i need to do CONFIGURE something before using this restful service. A doubt that i have is, if this is a restful service i found nothing about configuring its endpoint over internet. Even if you can provide some reference's that will also be great.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @DalmTo

Your post help me lot.
I did some research got a similar but little bit different solution.
I found a method in GmailApp class called search and sent a query(in:sent) as you suggested. This returned me all the sent mails.

I did something like this 
`var _sentMail = GmailApp.search('in:sent');`
This returned me array of GmailThread.

The one thing i did found that sent label in our gmail dashboard is not actually a label, its a method which takes a parameter "in:sent".